# Unable To Resolve module react-native-pager-view React Native

Tags: react-native, npm, react-native-pager-view

I am learning react native. When installing the app in simulator, i am facing an issue which is following. Please provide any solution.

If i install react-native-pager-view then it throws error. And when i uninstalled it. It is throwing following error-:

```
   Unable to resolve module react-native-pager-view in the root directory.
```

[image]

Comment: I have absolutely the same problem for 2 days, I managed to solve it yesterday with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63136085/9300663 .

Then today I installed a new package and the problem returned.
I keep investigating this issue, but we'll maybe have to open an issue on the react-native-pager-view repo...

Answer (score 10):

I've solved this issue by running:

```
yarn add react-native-pager-view
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running this command:

```
rm -rf yarn.lock node_modules ios/Pods ios/Podfile.lock && yarn install && cd ios && pod install && cd ..
```

Comment: I run this command and after also run ios -> pod install
 But same error, Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by doing pod install and removing some other dependencies. I install and uninstall this dependency several times. Finally i deleted this and at last it works. Restart vs code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using `material top tab navigation` from `react-navigation`,
and this requires some extra dependencies which you need to install before using react-navigation

for ref please visit [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/) official site.

To fix this, please run `yarn add react-native-tab-view react-native-pager-view` and then `pod install`

may be your problem will solve.